# unable to override command line arguments in Angularjs Protractor while running suites with gulp

Tags: angularjs, protractor, e2e-testing, gulp-protractor

I am able to set params in conf file. but when i run & try to override on runtime it's not working. it's login with username which i have mentioned in conf file.

my config file-

```
var Jasmine2HtmlReporter = require('protractor-jasmine2-html-reporter');
var log4js = require('log4js');
exports.config = {
  seleniumAddress: 'http://localhost:4444/wd/hub',
  allScriptsTimeout: 10*60*1000,
  framework: 'jasmine2',

  onPrepare: function () 

    browser.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(11000);
    var width = 768;
    var height = 1366;
    browser.driver.manage().window().setSize(768, 1366);
    //browser.ignoreSynchronization = true

    jasmine.getEnv().addReporter(
      new Jasmine2HtmlReporter({
        savePath: __dirname+'/qualityreports/testresults/e2e',
        takeScreenshots: false,
        filePrefix: 'automationReport',
        consolidate: true,
        cleanDestination: false,
        consolidateAll: true

      })
    );
  },

  suites:{
    suiteone:['./test/e2e/login/**/*Spec.js',
      './test/e2e/main/**/mainSpec.js']
  },
  capabilities: {
    'browserName': 'chrome',
    'chromeOptions': {
      'args': []
    }
  },

  appenders: [
    {
      "type": "file",
      "filename": "./e2eTestLogs/logfile.log",
      "maxLogSize": 20480,
      "backups": 3,
      "category": "relative-logger"
    }
  ],

  resultJsonOutputFile:'./results.txt',

  params: {
    Login: {
      username: 'xyz',
      password: 'xyz'
    }
  },

  // Options to be passed to Jasmine-node.
  jasmineNodeOpts: {
    showColors: true,
    defaultTimeoutInterval: 40*60*1000
  }
};
```

Command I used:

```
gulp e2e-test --suite suiteone --params.Login.username=abc --params.Login.password=abc
```

Could anyone please help here. I want to understand where i am doing mistake while passing command line argument.

Comment: I think this would work if you were not using gulp since you are using gulp you need to use argv to handle those command line arguments and pass them into your protractor task.

Comment: This i have already handle via yargs. here is my gulp file looks like. please take a look & let me know if something wrong i am doing.

Comment: var gulp = require('gulp');
var gulpProtractor = require('gulp-angular-protractor');
var args = require('yargs').argv;


 gulp.task('e2e-test',['transpile'], function(callback) {
     gulp.src(paths.tests)
         .pipe((gulpProtractor({
                 configFile: 'protractor.conf.js',
                 args: [
                   '--suite', args.suite
                 ],
         })).on('error', function(e) {
                 console.log(e);
             }).on('end', callback));
 });

Comment: Looks like the paths.tests you have included is the issue if you replace that with gulp.src([]) maybe it will work. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38436507/running-gulp-angular-protractor-without-gulp-src?rq=1

Comment: I am able to overwrite the same but i need to remove the yargs as this is the main thing which is not supporting params i did this way.

Comment: var params = process.argv;
var args = process.argv.slice(3);

Answer (score 0):

Try passing values in quote

```
--params.Login.username="abc"
```

Comment: Tried with double & single quotes as well but same it didn't overwrite.

Answer (score 0):

Try this one

```
--params.Login.username "abc"
```

It's described in the [documentation](https://github.com/angular/protractor/blob/master/lib/config.ts) of Protractor.